# How to pass url parameter with spaces in Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have developed web service using ASP.NET Web API for my application. Find code to access data's from WEP API

```
namespace ProjectTrackingServices.Controllers
{
   [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
    public class PTEmployeesController : ApiController
    {
 [Route("api/ptemployees/{name:alpha}")]
        public HttpResponseMessage Get(string name)
        {
            var employees = EmployeesRepository.SearchEmployeesByName(name);
            HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, employees);
            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

1. I can filter specific employee data's using their name , which has without space in name string. 
   ex: URL: http://localhost:55487/api/ptemployees/john
2. When i try to filter the employees with full name[ has spaces] by url
   ex: Url: " http://localhost:55487/api/ptemployees/john markus "
   Error will return
   "NetworkError: 400 Bad Request - http://localhost:55487/api/ptemployees/john%20m"

So anyone help how to pass url parameter with spaces and return success status in WEP API.

Comment: in API mapping you have mention {name:alpha} so alpha does not contain space so please change in URL mapping then try it

Comment: Dharmesh, Yes. when change the url mapping it's working fine

Comment: @Dharmesh whether you think your comment it's easy or obvious, you should include an answer with taht information to make it clear that this Q has an A, so that's useful for other people

Answer (score 4):

The problem is the attribute constriant in the route:

```
[Route("api/ptemployees/{name:alpha}")]
```

The `alpha` constraint requries that all the characters are alphabetic characters, and that doesn't include spaces. You need to remove or change your constraint (If you want to change it, the easiest way is to use a `regex` constraint).

From [the documentation on attribute routing](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#constraints):

> alpha Matches uppercase or lowercase Latin alphabet characters (a-z, A-Z)

Answer (score 2):

The person calling your API should make sure they encode the URL parameters as per the http specification. If the caller if using .net all url params should be passed through the [HttpUtility.UrlEncode()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urlencode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) static method. In the above case this will turn the url into http://localhost:55487/api/ptemployees/john%20markus

When calling the API, because it now conforms to the HTTP protocol, WEB API will know how to decode this with the proper spaces.

Comment: The answer was already in a comment. I asked the one who made the comment to covnert it into an answer, but, as he didn't I've done it myself. The URL encoding wasn't the problem in this occasion.